# Quebra de imagens (HTML, CSS, responsividade)

Tags: html, css, media-queries, e-commerce

Bom dia,

Meu problema é o seguinte: [image]

Estou usando o PrestaShop.
Preciso que aquelas imagens do print fiquem uma embaixo da outra, quando diminuir a resolução ou quando for acessada de um dispositivo móvel, pois assim elas ficam ilegíveis. Seria apenas deixa-las uma a baixo da outra, não sei se media querie resolveria.
Grato pela ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o código que você está usando para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Opa, esqueci desse detalhe, obrigado, e também dizer que estou usando o PrestaShop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude a div com a classe `"col-xs-4 col-sm-4"` para `"col-xs-12 col-sm-4"`. O grid do bootstrap funciona de resoluções menores para maiores. Caso coloque apenas col-xs-4 esse mesmo tamanho de grid será setado para todas resoluções como `sm md lg`. Colocando o `col-xs-12` as imagens ficaram uma abaixo da outra em resoluções menores e colocando `col-sm-4` o mesmo grid que foi mostrado será mantido para resoluções maiores.

Comment: Obrigado @matheuscla. Irei testar e lhe retorno, muito obrigado.

Comment: Funcionou, não tinha percebido isso cara, haha. Obrigadão mesmo.